# Ram Usage of Db rapildy increasing how free up it

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb

In my db it is 32 gb ram but it fill now 24 gb rapidly. After hiiting the 32 mark the db restarted automatically . I have set the buufer size 27gb. then also it increasing.How do i free up the ram aor any solution reagarding to it. And my db server is on aws server.

I have set the innodbbuffer size27gb.

Answer (score 0):

First, capture all the settings.  Please provide these (in any machine-readable format):

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

There are a dozen other things that *could* be causing trouble.

Then (right away) change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to only `20G` (and restart MySQL/MariaDB).  This will give you breathing room while we figure out what really needs changing.